# iOS JSON serialization empty array serialized as nil instead of [ ]

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I am attempting to send some JSON to a Rails backend. When serializing payload (NSDictionary), an empty array is encoding as nil instead of [ ] (empty array).

Is JSON encoding an empty NSArray as [] not supported on iOS?

I have tried changing the 'options' within dataWithJSONObject: with no success. 
Sending along @"[]" as a regular ol' NSString also does not work.

Here is the code:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:payload options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
AFJSONRequestOperation *authRequest = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request  success:successBlock failure:failBlock];
[authRequest start];
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have seen the opposite in other languages, where an empty array is used because the language has no NSNull equivalent.  Guess I've never had call to send an empty array on iOS.

Comment: You can always try one of the other dozen or so JSON implementations for Objective-C.

Comment: I suggest you pass in the address of an `NSError *` object to the `error:` argument and then check it upon return.

Comment: The string `[]` is definitely valid JSON.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The dictionary `@{@"key": @[]}` is converted to the JSON data `{"key":[]}`.

Comment: (I missed where you said it's returning `nil` -- was thinking it was returning the (unquoted) string `null`, which is, well, the JSON representation for null.  `nil` always indicates an error.)

Comment: @MartinR Me too, it seems to be working OK

Comment: Has anyone tried an empty NSArray as the outermost object?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, it's also working OK

Comment: Btw., `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` is an option to *read* JSON, not to *write* JSON.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your actual `payload`, and the output of `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`.

Comment: You mentioned that `payload` is `NSDictionary`, so why do you have an empty array `[]` as the top level object? Also, sending `NSString` containing `@"[]"`… where? Into the JSON serialization method?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is coming from Rails and not from iOS, there is an issue related to a security hole in Rails since 3.2.11

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8832

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/82

For example :

Sending an empty array in your body `{"bookmarks":[]}`

Gets serialized in Rails as : `{"bookmarks"=>nil}`

To be sure where the problem is coming from you should inspect the request using a proxy like Charles.